# how to show a SUM column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to show a summaries of a column with the SUM() function in PHP.

I'm using `$pointsummary= "SELECT SUM(points) FROM result WHERE id=$val";` to call my SUM function but i cant show it in my PHP. I've tried `$test = mysqli_fetch_array($pointsummary);` and then echo `$test[0];` but it wont work. 
When i do this i get:

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

What should i do?

Comment: Hi Homam Zraki, what type of a field is points in MySQL?

Comment: @aharen its numbers.. and i want to get the result of summing them up

Comment: he meant the column's "type" and not the "content". `int`? `varchar`? other?

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, its int

Comment: is your `points` column the first column in your db, or is it the second? arrays are zero-indexed. Meaning that you're trying to get the index of `id` rather than `points` if `id` is your first column. Therefore, you'd need to do `$test[1];` if `points` is the 2nd column.

Comment: **Show the real code** Then we can stop guessing. It looks to me like you have missed at least one step out of the query -> read result processing

Comment: well, you've been given an answer below which makes sense. Try it out and if it works, great. If not, let the guy know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error is caused by the fact that `$pointsummary` is a string and not a mysqli_result object. you need to use [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) first and use what that returns. eg.

```
$resultObj = mysqli_query($con, $pointsummary); // <--- $con is what you got from mysqli_connect()
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($resultObj);
```

Another note is that with `SELECT SUM(points) FROM result` i would suggest aliasing `SUM(points)` with a name you'll recognize so that instead of having to var_dump the key/values of the `mysqli_fetch_array` to find what the array key is for `SUM(points)` you'll know before hand.

to do this use `AS`. ie

```
SELECT SUM(points) AS `summary` FROM result
```

Comment: Memor-X Good answer as far as it goes. But can I suggest you add a few lines of sample code. I dont thing the questioner knows that he missed out the `$result = mysqli_query($con, $pointsummary);` step completely

Comment: I think the OP's gone to make some popcorn and headed off to the movies or something, maybe even meet up at a secret *No tell Motel*, who knows. No word from them since a few comments ago. Question's unclear, far as I'm concerned and we don't know even if they're using the same API to connect with etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

@Memor-X answer is good but I have a feeling that you have missed at least one step in the normal flow of event when querying a database in PHP using `mysqli_`

```
// create a query as a text string
$pointsummary = "SELECT SUM(points) as `tot_points` 
                 FROM result 
                 WHERE id=$val";

// issue the query to the MySQL Server for execution
// this should create a result set as long as the query is valid
$result = mysqli_query($con, $pointsummary);

// Check that the query had no errors
if ( ! $result ) {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
    exit;
}

// request the first row from the result set
// as we know this query will only return one row
// we dont need to do this in a loop
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['tot_points'];
```